# Looping through worksheet to create a graph in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I am trying to create a graph based on some data from a worksheet. I have a code that creates the graph.

**PROBLEM** 
I am trying to loop through the worksheets in my workbook to check if the graph is already there, in that case I activate it, clean the previous data and put new data in.

If it is not, I create a new graph and put the data in.

I tried to create a double loop to check if the names of the worksheet match, but that does not work (cannot set the chart to nothing).

Any ideas on what to do?

**Current Code (only the relevant part)**

```
Set RetRange = w.Sheets("Ret").UsedRange
  ' Set RetRange = w.Sheets("Returns Output").Range(w.Sheets("Ret").Cells("A1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell))

'if graph is already there, change       
Set RetChart = Nothing

For Each ws In w.Worksheets
    If ws.Name = "RetGraph" Then         
        Set RetChart = Charts("Ret").Activate    
    Else

    End If
Next ws

If RetChart = Nothing Then
    Set RetChart = Charts.Add        
End If

With RetChart
    .Select                
    .ChartType = xlLine                
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = "Index Performance"
    .SetSourceData Source:=RetRange
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Date"
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Return"
    .Name = "RetGraph"
    .Legend.Select
     Selection.position = xlBottom
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Name` "Ret" is the property of `ChartObject`, not the `Chart`.

The highest hierarchy is `ChartObject`, underneath it you can find `Chart`, `Name` and many others, see short diagram below:

```
ChartObject
--> Chart
  |--> ChartArea
  |--> Axes
  |--> SeriesCollection
     |--> Format.Line
--> Name
--> Top 
--> Left  
--> Height
--> Width
```

**Comment**: I recommend using the `ChartObject` and then you can easily nest underneath to modify all the other properties. Also, there is almost allways no reason to use `Select` and `Selection` but ise fully qualified `ChartObjects` and it's nested properties.

The code below, will loop through all `Worksheets`, and then for each `Worksheet` will loop through all `ChartObjects`, and search for "Ret".

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub LoopSheets_ChartObjects()

Dim RetChart As Chart
Dim ChtObj As ChartObject
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim w As Workbook

Set w = ThisWorkbook

For Each ws In w.Worksheets
    If ws.Name = "RetGraph" Then
        For Each ChtObj In ws.ChartObjects
            If ChtObj.Name = "Ret" Then '<-- if there is a match
                Set RetChart = ChtObj.Chart ' <-- set chart to ChartObject.Chart
            End If
        Next ChtObj
    End If
 Next ws

If RetChart Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "NOT Found"
    ' do your coding stuff
End If

End Sub
```

**Edit 1**:  to support PO new information, chart is placed in a Chart Sheet.

```
Dim RetChart As Chart
Dim Cht_Sht As Chart

For Each Cht_Sht In w.Charts
    If Cht_Sht.Name = "RetGraph" Then
        Set RetChart = Cht_Sht
    End If
Next Cht_Sht

If RetChart Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "NOT Found"
    ' do your coding stuff

Else ' <-- chart found
    RetChart.ChartTitle.Text = "Test" '<-- for debug only
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand you looped through the charts in a worksheet. My mistake is that I am creating charts in a Chart sheet. 

I am now trying to loop through it and see if the chart already exists. If it does not, create a chart.

Answer (score 0):

you can avoid looping through sheets

```
Dim RetChart As Chart

On Error Resume Next
Set RetChart = w.Charts("RetGraph")
On Error GoTo 0

If RetChart Is Nothing Then '<--| chart not found
    MsgBox "NOT Found"
    ' do your coding stuff
Else ' <--| chart found
    RetChart.ChartTitle.Text = "Test" '<-- for debug only
End If
```